# Netlify CMS with self-hosted Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, netlify, netlify-cms

I have a Gatsby static site that is currently deployed via Zeit Now from a self-hosted [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) account.

I would like to add [Netlify CMS](https://www.netlifycms.org/), but it [only seems to integrate with a Gitlab.com account](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/authentication-backends/).

**Is it possible to use Netlify CMS with a self-hosted Gitlab account?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will be able to use **Netlify CMS** with a self-hosted **Gitlab** server [using Implicit Grant](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/authentication-backends/#client-side-implicit-grant)

As the docs show, your options are below for the `backend` in the `config.yml` file:

```json
backend:
  name: gitlab
  repo: owner-name/repo-name # Path to your GitLab repository
  auth_type: implicit # Required for implicit grant
  app_id: your-app-id # Application ID from your GitLab settings
  api_root: https://my-hosted-gitlab-instance.com/api/v4
  base_url: https://my-hosted-gitlab-instance.com
  auth_endpoint: oauth/authorize
```

**On Gitlab:** Setup an [application on Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/oauth_provider.html#adding-an-application-through-the-profile) to get the `app_id` and to set the Redirect URI, enter the address where you access Netlify CMS, for example, https://www.example.com/admin/. For scope, select **api**

**Update:** It is recommended to use [client-side PKCE Authorization](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/gitlab-backend/#client-side-pkce-authorization) now for Gitlab rather than Implicit Grant.

Comment: I've made an update to this answer for those looking to use Auth for Gitlab with Netlify CMS. PKCE is going to be a more secure solution.

Answer (score 0):

By using [Netlify CLI](https://www.netlify.com/docs/cli/) you set it up to auto-deploy from Self-hosted/managed GitLab.

You'll need to configure **SSH key** and **webhook integration**. Here is a detailed guide: [Auto Deploy to Netlify from Self-hosted GitLab](https://coffeencoding.com/auto-deploy-to-netlify-from-self-hosted-gitlab/)

Comment: The OP wants to use Netlify CMS, not Netlify (which is a different thing, it's a hosting service)

Netlify CLI works only with Netlify.